# how can I have every excel workbook I open to have columns.autofit property?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to write a macro or adjust Excel properties, so that whenever I open a new excel workbook all values are autofited to the columns.

I tried using the following code, which works if I save the code for a specific workbook, however if I save the code in the PERSONAL workbook, the code produces an error. "Method 'Columns' of object '_Global' failed"

```
Sub auto_open()
   Columns().AutoFit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do this is to create a simple add-in that handles Application events I want to intercept.  The reason that it doesn't work in the auto_open() is because you are trying to work with the Columns object before it gets instantiated.  Much better to use the SheetActivate event.  This also avoids the possibility of opening a Workbook with 20 pages and having to wait for all of them to AutoFit.  You only ***see*** the active sheet, right?

The concept is to grab a reference WithEvents to the application and set up handlers to whatever events you care about.  To do this, you'll have to put the code into a class.  I called mine "AppHolder".

Class code:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents app As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set app = Application

End Sub

Private Sub app_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Sh.Columns().AutoFit

End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

    Wb.ActiveSheet.Columns().AutoFit

End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookNewSheet(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Sh As Object)

    Sh.Columns().AutoFit

End Sub
```

Then, create an instance of your class in and set it in auto_open (or Workbook_Open as the case may be) in the ThisWorkbook module:

```
Option Explicit
Private hook As AppHolder

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Set hook = New AppHolder

End Sub
```

Save it as an Excel add-in file (.xlam) in the default location - should be in Users[You]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns.  Close Excel and re-open it, then go to Developer...Add-Ins and enable it.  All there is to it.

EDIT: Almost forgot - that doesn't cover all situations in which you'll be presented with a Worksheet.  You need WorkbookActivate and WorkbookNewSheet too...

Comment: Thanks. In addition I was forced to learn about events and classes, which was something I have not used so far. For final code I have used app_SheetActivate and app_SheetChange, in my opinion it should cover all the cases I need.

Answer (score 0):

This might work :

```
Sub auto_open()
For i = 1 To Application.Workbooks.Count
    For j = 1 To Application.Workbooks(i).Sheets.Count
        For k = 1 To Application.Workbooks(i).Sheets(j).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Application.Workbooks(i).Sheets(j).Columns(k).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Next k
    Next j
    Application.Workbooks(i).Save
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error. "Method 'Columns' of object '_Global' failed"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the "EntireColumn", this should work

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this: (**untested**)

```
Sub auto_open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each wb In Workbooks
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ws.Columns.AutoFit
    Next ws
Next wb

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Its important to identify the Objects you are working on (in this case *workbooks* and *worksheets*) because it helps you to know which method you could apply to them ([see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820840.aspx))

Comment: Thanks, however the code you provided does not work.

Comment: Run-time error '1004' "Method 'Calculation' of object '_Application' failed. Did you test your code by adding it to the PERSONAL workbook?